# Angular 13 : how to get http request body object type?

Tags: javascript, angular, httpresponse, interceptor, instanceof

I don't know if my question is legit or not, but I am trying to intercept every message from my api for dispose it in a popup via an interceptor :

```js
    export class ApiMessageInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(request).pipe(
            tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
              if (event instanceof HttpResponse && JSON.parse(event.body) instanceof AlertMessage ) { //here I am trying to know if the object in the body is an AlertMessage type or not
                this.dialog.open(AlertMessageComponent, {
                    width: '600px',
                    data: event.body
                  });
              }
            })
        );
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work. I mean, my interceptor intercepts the httpresponses very well, I can check the content in the body via the debugger, and everything is ok. But instanceOf check doesn't work at all.

So, any idea of how can I check the object type in the body?

Thanks.

EDIT :

AlertMessage class :

```
import { AlertMessageType } from "../enum/alert-message.type";

export class AlertMessage {

public content?: string;
public type?: AlertMessageType;

constructor(content?: string, type?: AlertMessageType) {
    this.content = content;
    this.type = type;
}
```

}

Body console.log :

```
{content: "L'identifiant ou le mot de passe est incorrect.", type: 1}
content: "L'identifiant ou le mot de passe est incorrect."
type: 1
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

EDIT 2 :

I tried something like that :

```
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
        tap((event: HttpEvent<HttpResponse<AlertMessage>>) => {
          if (event instanceof HttpResponse && event.body?.body instanceof AlertMessage) {
            this.dialog.open(AlertMessageComponent, {
                width: '600px',
                data: event.body.body
              });
          }
        })
    );
}
```

The first 'body' for HttpResponse type and the second is an AlertMessage Type, recognized as such in VS Code. But when I try it on live, both are undefined :((((

Very bizzare

Comment: Can you add to the question the `AlertMessage` class and `console.log(req.body)`?

Comment: I added an EDIT 1 and 2

Comment: You can't check the "type" of the response body - it's a generic (plain) JS object. You have to check its properties to determine it's "data type" (duck typing).

Comment: I see. Thank you for your response @TsvetanGanev.

Can you give me a concret exemple with my code linked in the question please? Thank you again.

Comment: Ok I found a solution. Very bizarre and in my opinion ugly solution, but it works, so I keep it for now, and may be change it for better thing in the future. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`instanceof` relies on `Symbol.hasInstance` which gets set behind the scenes when a constructor is called. `JSON.parse` just creates an instance of `Object` so it won't match to custom classes by default.

To make `instanceof` match arbitrary objects to a custom class you can override the default behaviour like described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/hasInstance

You can make it check the types of primitives, or even the `instanceof` of other objects. You can run any code to validate that this is the correct object type.

```
export class AlertMessage {

  static [Symbol.hasInstance](instance) {
    return (
      typeof instance.content === 'string' &&
      ...
    );
  }
  ...
}
```

I don't know what `AlertMessageType` is so I can't add the code to validate that property.

### Example

```js
class AlertMessage {
  static [Symbol.hasInstance](instance) {
    return (
      typeof instance.content === 'string' && typeof instance.code === 'number'
    );
  }
}

console.log({ content: 'test', code: 1 } instanceof AlertMessage);
```

Comment: Crazy ! Thanks alot Chris :) Your solution works perfectly and is far more elegant than mine :p

Comment: By the way, AlertMessageType is an enum, precise if is a fail or success message.